# 3D Connexion Space Mouse stops responding during Blender operations

Tags: modeling, camera, knife-tool, 3d-mouse

As the question title suggests, I have a minor problem with Blender's implementation of Space mouse/3D mouse control.  I finally got the actual *operation* of the 3D mouse to be like I want.  Except this point.  Anytime that I do an operation in Blender, like say scaling or rotating part of a mesh, while that operation is being performed the space mouse refuses to function.  While this does not initially *seem* to be a big deal, it can cause some serious frustrations!

Take for example doing a knife cut.  If the object isn't fit entirely on the screen, or simply is unable to be, and you need to start a knife cut that goes up an object far enough to go off the screen, your space mouse is useless at that time!  Because, the actual knife operation freezes space mouse input, thus when you try to pull up on the space mouse to move the view up the model to continue the knife cut, nothing happens.  Forcing you to go back to regular keyboard/mouse based camera movement to slide up to continue the cut!

This is exactly the sort of thing you get a space mouse for, to be able to do operations with the regular mouse while also operating the camera with the space mouse!  Am I just stupid and I've missed a setting that changes this, or is this 'built in' behavior to Blender and thus, without tweaks from the software developers, I'll never see relief?

Comment: First look here: http://www.3dconnexion.com/index.php?id=108&redirect2=www.3dconnexion.com after that maybe tell us what OS are you using? Do you have drivers installed properly?

Comment: While I expect 3D mouse movement during scaling won't happen, you should be able to move around while using the knife tool, with both a normal and a 3D mouse. I would say report it as a bug and see if the devs say it is working as intended, especially if the normal mouse works when the 3D mouse stops.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a 3D mouse issue, this is a well known general Blender limitation.

Most of those operators are modals (*Knife Project*, *Extrude*, *Translate* etc), and while they are running one cant access any other operators, until operation is terminated (that also includes viewport navigation operators like *Move View* or *Rotate View*). Bottom line is this is also an issue with regular mouse and keyboard.

Things may yet improve for the [upcoming 2.8 series](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.8/UI/Workshop_Writeup), but nothing is written in stone.